# UserWarning: FixedFormatter should only be used together with FixedLocator

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have used for a long time small subroutines to format axes of charts I'm plotting. A couple of examples:

```
def format_y_label_thousands(): # format y-axis tick labels formats
    ax = plt.gca()
    label_format = '{:,.0f}'
    ax.set_yticklabels([label_format.format(x) for x in ax.get_yticks().tolist()])

def format_y_label_percent(): # format y-axis tick labels formats
    ax = plt.gca()
    label_format = '{:.1%}'
    ax.set_yticklabels([label_format.format(x) for x in ax.get_yticks().tolist()])
```

However, after an update to matplotlib yesterday, I get the following warning when calling any of these two functions:

```
UserWarning: FixedFormatter should only be used together with FixedLocator
  ax.set_yticklabels([label_format.format(x) for x in ax.get_yticks().tolist()])
```

What is the reason for such a warning? I couldn't figure it out looking into matplotlib's documentation.

Comment: Same here. Just let me comment that it is not an error but a warning. I'm sure people will mention it in their answers.

Comment: Have you read the doc at https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/ticker_api.html? It says "FixedFormatter should only be used together with FixedLocator. Otherwise, the labels may end up in unexpected positions". This may help?

Comment: Thank you @fra_pero for the warning vs. error detail. I just corrected it. I did see the material you pointed to on the link above, but I couldn't use the info there to fix my code. Please vote the question up: hopefully, it will attrack more attention to it.

Comment: It seems to be a bug in the latest version of matplotlib (3.3.1). I found [this bug-report](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35684) in the github-page of pandas, where they discover the solution is to issue the `set_xticks` method before the `set_xticklabels`. It should probably work with the `y` direction as well.

Comment: Issue at [Matplotlib](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/18848): *"That's on purpose. You should also explicitly specify the three ticks to go with the label and then this warning should go away.

OTOH I agree the warning is pretty mysterious if u are just using set_xticklabels."*

Comment: If you're like me and were simply trying to rotate the axis labels without any other changes, the following answer on stack overflow avoids the warning: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52461208/768439.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

**WORKAROUND:**

The way to avoid the warning is to use FixedLocator (that is part of matplotlib.ticker). Below I show a code to plot three charts. I format their axes in different ways. Note that the "set_ticks" silence the warning, but it changes the actual ticks locations/labels (it took me some time to figure out that FixedLocator uses the same info but keeps the ticks locations intact). You can play with the x/y's to see how each solution might affect the output.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

mpl.rcParams['font.size'] = 6.5

x = np.array(range(1000, 5000, 500))
y = 37*x

fig, [ax1, ax2, ax3] = plt.subplots(1,3)

ax1.plot(x,y, linewidth=5, color='green')
ax2.plot(x,y, linewidth=5, color='red')
ax3.plot(x,y, linewidth=5, color='blue')

label_format = '{:,.0f}'

# nothing done to ax1 as it is a "control chart."

# fixing yticks with "set_yticks"
ticks_loc = ax2.get_yticks().tolist()
ax2.set_yticks(ax1.get_yticks().tolist())
ax2.set_yticklabels([label_format.format(x) for x in ticks_loc])

# fixing yticks with matplotlib.ticker "FixedLocator"
ticks_loc = ax3.get_yticks().tolist()
ax3.yaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.FixedLocator(ticks_loc))
ax3.set_yticklabels([label_format.format(x) for x in ticks_loc])

# fixing xticks with FixedLocator but also using MaxNLocator to avoid cramped x-labels
ax3.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(3))
ticks_loc = ax3.get_xticks().tolist()
ax3.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.FixedLocator(ticks_loc))
ax3.set_xticklabels([label_format.format(x) for x in ticks_loc])

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

OUTPUT CHARTS:

[image: Sample charts]

Obviously, having a couple of idle lines of code like the one above (I'm basically getting the yticks or xticks and setting them again) only adds noise to my program. I would prefer that the warning was removed. However, look into some of the "bug reports" (from links on the comments above/below; the issue is not actually a bug: it is an update that is generating some issues), and the contributors that manage matplotlib have their reasons to keep the warning.

**OLDER VERSION OF MATPLOTLIB:**
If you use your Console to control critical outputs of your code (as I do), the warning messages might be problematic. Therefore, a way to delay having to deal with the issue is to downgrade matplotlib to version 3.2.2. I use Anaconda to manage my Python packages, and here is the command used to downgrade matplotlib:

```
conda install matplotlib=3.2.2
```

Not all listed versions might be available. For instance, couldn't install matplotlib 3.3.0 although it is listed on matplotlib's releases page: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/releases

Comment: Happy to help. Consider accepting your own answer to this question for now, due to it resolving your issue at the moment. If you find a future solution, you can update this post with the new solution.

Comment: Has a bug been reported against matplotlib?

Comment: P.S: Apparently not. Doing it now.

Comment: Hello @Ilya: I'm assuming [a recent bug report on Github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/18848) was you. I had added a comment to a prior bug-report (see comments at the original post above) that was merged into another issue. Hopefully, they will revise it soon (I will add a note here if there is a solution). I nevertheless added an extra comment on your bug-report. I hope the decision is to remove the warning when one only formats existing ticks labels: otherwise I will have to include an 'idle' line of code to avoid the warning (which messes up my console outputs).

Comment: Yeah, that was me.

Answer (score 91):

If someone comes here using the function `axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels()` (or yaxis equivalent), you don't need to use FixedLocator, you can avoid this warning using `axes.xaxis.set_ticks(values_list)` **BEFORE** `axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels(labels_list)`.

Comment: I keep bumping into this warning and back to your answer! The data/plot-agnostic solution is: `ax.set_yticks(ax.get_yticks().tolist()); ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks().tolist())`.

Comment: Minor correction to **pds**'s comment. I just tried this and it seems that `ax.get_xticks()` already returns a list. I don't think its necessary to call the (non-existent?) method `.tolist()`. Otherwise this works perfectly to get rid of that `UserWarning`!

Comment: Whoops! Good catch @als0052. Here's the string for the next time: `ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()); ax.set_yticks(ax.get_yticks())`

Answer (score 30):

I had the same problem as I tried to rotate the tick labels on the X-axis with located date ticks:

```
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.DayLocator())
```

It worked out using the 'tick_params()' method:

```
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation = 45)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm fine with this answer.

Comment: But then how do you incorporate the `horizontalalignment='left'` option? That only seems available for `ax.set_xticklabels`

Answer (score 11):

According to this matplotlib [page](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks/tick-formatters.html)

```
# FixedFormatter should only be used together with FixedLocator. 
# Otherwise, one cannot be sure where the labels will end up.
```

This means one should do

```
from matplotlib import ticker

positions = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(positions))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(labels))
```

But the issue also persisted with the `ticker.LogLocator` even if the labels were passed to `ticker.FixedFormatter`.
So the solution in this case was

1. Define a formatter function

   ```
   # FuncFormatter can be used as a decorator
   @ticker.FuncFormatter
   def major_formatter(x, pos):
       return f'{x:.2f}'
   ```
2. and pass the formatter function to the FixedFormatter

   ```
   ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.LogLocator(base=10, numticks=5))
   ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(major_formatter)
   ```

See the above link for details.

Comment: also: `from matplotlib import ticker`

Answer (score 6):

I solved just adding this sentence:

```
ax.set_xticks([1,2,3])
ax.set_xtickslabels(['Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest workaround is to suppress warnings (this includes UserWarning):

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

The use-case would be if you don't want your jupyter notebook on github to look trashed with warning messages. Unlike most warnings, this warning keeps repeating if you're in a loop (python 3.7).

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using a `seaborn` `heatmap` and this is how I fixed it:

This was throwing the warning `UserWarning: FixedFormatter should only be used together with FixedLocator cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(cbar.ax.get_yticklabels(), rotation=90, va='center')`

```
heatmap = sb.heatmap(pd.DataFrame(full_dict).T.fillna(0), annot=True, linewidths=1, xticklabels=1, yticklabels=1, annot_kws={'rotation': 90})
cbar = heatmap.collections[0].colorbar
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(cbar.ax.get_yticklabels(), rotation=90, va='center')
```

I changed it to the following in order to suppress the warning:

```
heatmap = sb.heatmap(pd.DataFrame(full_dict).T.fillna(0), annot=True, linewidths=1, xticklabels=1, yticklabels=1, annot_kws={'rotation': 90})
cbar = heatmap.collections[0].colorbar
cbar.ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelrotation=90)
```

Thanks to @Rami's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72099702/264802

Answer (score 1):

##### Code:

```
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks())
ax.set_yticks(ax.get_yticks())
```

**^ this removes the warning for every data/plot case I've encountered.**

I keep bumping into this warning and to [**@dansarmo's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68794383/1910555). It is basically their answer. Thanks for correction by **@als0052** and **@Hampus Larsson's** comment for noting the [bug report](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35684) and solution with `set_*ticks`.

Comment: solved it with this answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also have the  UserWarning: FixedFormatter should only be used together with FixedLocator warning when doing:

```
 ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(bymonthday=ttick_solar))
 ax2.set_xticklabels(label_solar)
```

I tried to encapsulate mdates.DayLocator(bymonthday=ttick_solar) in a mticker.FixedLocator but i must do it wrongly.
What would be the correct syntax to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My case was a simple thing, I was customizing ticks before creating the plot itself, which resulted in trying to format something that had not been set to my expected number of ticks yet.

Make sure that if for example you are making a boxplot, edit the ticks AFTER the `plt.boxplot()` call.

Answer (score -6):

just use `axis.set_xticks([labels])`