# Change month labels in matplotlib without changing the locale

Tags: python, matplotlib

With this plot as an example:
[image]

With the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook

data = cbook.get_sample_data('goog.npz', np_load=True)['price_data'][0:200]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 7), constrained_layout=True)
ax.plot('date', 'adj_close', data=data)
# ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
# ax.grid(True)
ax.set_ylabel(r'Price [\$]')

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(
    mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(ax.xaxis.get_major_locator()))

plt.savefig("chart.png")
```

And I need to change the months from English to Spanish, ie: Dec to Dic, Apr to Abr, Jan to Ene and so on.

I can do it by changing the locale like so:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'es_ES')
```

But I can't use it in the script because it runs on a serverless vm where you can't change any of the os configuration.

So I thought in changing the labels "manually" from an English month to a Spanish one. I've seen examples using `DateFormatter` but that doesn't work because again it relies in the system locale for the months names using `strftime` and any other fromatter I've seen has been using numbers not dates. So is there any solution to localize the names of the months?

Update
Added solution [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75068683/1128695)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `babel.dates` for the date formatting, which allows for a locale argument without changing the system locale.

The basic syntax is:

```
babel.dates.format_datetime([datetime object], [format], locale=[locale])
```

Note that the format does not use `%` signs. See the [package documentation](https://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/api/dates.html#babel.dates) for more information and many examples.

To use this package to format Matplotlib tick labels you can re-implement `DateFormatter` from the [matplotlib source](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/dc0328fb9c1c8817b07a5121a106a06be3571433/lib/matplotlib/dates.py#L616) and replace the `strftime()` call with `babel.dates.format_datetime()`.

As a proof of concept:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
import babel.dates

class CustomDateFormatter(mdates.ticker.Formatter):
   
    def __init__(self, fmt, fmtloc, tz=None, *, usetex=None):
        self.tz = mdates.UTC
        self.fmt = fmt
        self.fmtloc = fmtloc
        self._usetex = (usetex if usetex is not None else
                        mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'])

    def __call__(self, x, pos=0):
        result = babel.dates.format_datetime(mdates.num2date(x, self.tz), self.fmt, locale=self.fmtloc)
        return mdates._wrap_in_tex(result) if self._usetex else result

data = cbook.get_sample_data('goog.npz', np_load=True)['price_data'][0:200]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 7), constrained_layout=True)
ax.plot('date', 'adj_close', data=data)
ax.set_ylabel(r'Price [\$]')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(
    CustomDateFormatter("MMM yyyy", "es"))

plt.savefig("chart.png")
```

Result:

[image]

For `ConciseDateFormatter` this idea is the same but this class is much more complex so you will need to modify it in many places in order to get the namespaces right (similar to for example `mdates.num2date` in the code above instead of a plain `num2dates` call in the original class).

Comment: Thanks for your answer I learned a lot from it. And yes the `ConciseDateFormatter ` code is too complicated to understand that's why I thought a sort of label translation would be easier to do. It seems that all date related things are overly complicated

Comment: I posted an answer the changes the labels with `set_xticklabels` and Babel

Comment: @PerseP that is a good solution, much easier than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

Using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63755285/1128695) and the answer by [Marijn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75051766/1128695) I came up with this solution that uses `set_xticklabels` to change the labels and [Babel](https://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/) to change the months to a localized version without changing the `locale`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
import babel.dates
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

data = cbook.get_sample_data('goog.npz', np_load=True)['price_data'][0:200]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 7), constrained_layout=True)
ax.plot('date', 'adj_close', data=data)
# ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
# ax.grid(True)
ax.set_ylabel(r'Price [\$]')

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(
    mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(ax.xaxis.get_major_locator()))

ticks_loc = ax.get_xticks().tolist()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.FixedLocator(ticks_loc))
ax.set_xticklabels([babel.dates.format_datetime(mdates.num2date(x),'yyyy',locale='es') 
        if mdates.num2date(x).month == 1
        else babel.dates.format_datetime(mdates.num2date(x),'MMM',locale='es')
        for x in ticks_loc])

plt.savefig("chart.png")
```

It produces:

[image]