# rotating x labels in subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, x-axis, xticks

this is my code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize = (30, 8))
g1 = sns.lineplot(data = plsWeekly , x = 'Date', y = 'Close', ax=ax[0])
plt.xticks(rotation=70)
g2 = sns.lineplot(data = asxWeekly , x = 'Date', y = 'Close', ax=ax[1])
plt.xticks(rotation=70)
```

and, this is the output:

[image: subplot output]

i just tried running the code and I expected that
both x labels for the two(2) plots are gonna rotate
by 70

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52461208/12639940)

Comment: try this:

`fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize = (30, 8))`
`ax[0].xticks(rotation=70)`
`ax[1].xticks(rotation=70)`
`g1 = sns.lineplot(data = plsWeekly , x = 'Date', y = 'Close', ax=ax[0])`
`g2 = sns.lineplot(data = asxWeekly , x = 'Date', y = 'Close', ax=ax[1])`

Comment: @KayvanShah sorry, but, can you expound more? Python is asking definition for the xticks

Answer (score 0):

Set the current axes as needed before calling `plt.xticks(rotation=70)`, e.g.
`plt.sca(ax[0])`