# rotation of xticks in seaborn subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGkVd.png)I am trying to do rotation for my shared x axis xticks but the rotation works for some of the subplots and not for others. Could anyone point out my mistake

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [15.00, 7]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
plt.tight_layout()

fig,ax = plt.subplots(3,2, sharex =True)
plt.xticks(rotation=45);

#fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4, wspace=0.4)

sns.lineplot(ax=ax[0,0],x='YEAR',y ='GDP',data=data1, label ='GDP')
ax[0,0].title.set_text('GDP with DATE')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

sns.lineplot(ax=ax[0,1],x='YEAR',y='mediansoldprice',data=data1)
ax[0,1].title.set_text('mediansoldprice with DATE')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

sns.lineplot(ax=ax[1,0],x='YEAR',y='interestrates',data=data1,label ='interestrates')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
sns.lineplot(ax=ax[1,1],x='YEAR',y='30yr_fixed_mortigage',data=data1, 
label='30yr_fixed_mortigage')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
sns.lineplot(ax=ax[2,0],x='YEAR',y='homeindex',data=data1,label ='homeindex')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you provide the test data?

Comment: Where is it working and where is it not?

Comment: I have added my image could you able to see that ?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell exactly what your problem is without test data and a description or image of the specific plot failure, but the issue is mostly likely that you are calling `plt.xticks(rotation=45)` rather than setting the rotation for each subplot. You can use `matplotlib` methods to set the rotation, and there are several ways to do that as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186019/rotate-tick-labels-in-subplot). Here is a minimum example that you could modify for your plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [i**2 for i in x]

sns.lineplot(ax=ax[0,0], x = x, y = y)
ax[0,0].tick_params("x",labelrotation=45)

sns.lineplot(ax=ax[0,1], x = x, y = y)
ax[0,1].tick_params("x",labelrotation=45)

sns.lineplot(ax=ax[1,0], x = x, y = y)
ax[1,0].tick_params("x",labelrotation=45)

sns.lineplot(ax=ax[1,1], x = x, y = y)
ax[1,1].tick_params("x",labelrotation=45)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]