# Rotation labels matplotlib

Tags: python, csv, pandas, matplotlib

I have data

```
used_at                2014      2015
address                                                                                                  
auto.ru             9122342   6923367
am.ru                413071    183402
avito.ru           84503151  87688571
avtomarket.ru        106849     95927
cars.mail.ru/sale    211456    167278
```

and i need to print graph with rotation
`address`   .
I print

```
ax = graph_by_duration.plot.bar(width=0.5, ax=axes[0])
ax.set_xticklabels(graph_by_duration, rotation=40)
```

but it doesn't work. How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotate axis text in python matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998621/rotate-axis-text-in-python-matplotlib)

Comment: If you want to ask a new question **go ask a new question**. Do not completely change your question and uncheck the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that this is failing is because `set_xticklabels` expects a list of strings as it's first input and you are passing a DataFrame. One option is to call `plt.xticks()` *prior* to plotting.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.xticks(rotation=40)
ax = graph_by_duration.plot.bar(width=0.5, ax=axes[0])
```

The other option is to set the rotation on the existing labels by first fetching all labels.

```
for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
    label.set_rotation(40)
```