# How to rotate x-axis labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels, x-axis

I am trying to rotate the xaxis labels but the xticks function below has no effect and the labels overwrite each other

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
     corrmat = X.corr()
     plt.xticks(rotation=90)       
     plt.figure(figsize=(15,16))          
     ax = sns.heatmap(corrmat, vmin=0, vmax=1)
     ax.xaxis.tick_top()
```

[image: Jumbled xaxis]

After using suggested code changes: I get the following but I still want to increase the size of the heatmap

[image: How to increase the size of this heatmap]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setp` looks to be the way to go with pyplot (inspiration from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10998872/3697870)). This works for me:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)

data = np.random.rand(10, 12)
ax = sns.heatmap(data)
ax.xaxis.tick_top()
locs, labels = plt.xticks()
plt.setp(labels, rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Obviously I don't have your data, hence the numpy random data, but otherwise the effect is as required:

[image]

Comment: I updated my question with your code (with some modifications). How do I increase the size of this heatmap?

Comment: Sounds like a new question that no longer matches this one. If your original question has been answered, please accept this answer and repost as a new question. This is a Q&A site, not a tech support discussion site.