# Rotating x-axis labels in python xy

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I have strings as my x-axis labels and I need to rotate them to be veritcal so that they fit on the actual axis. I can't find any answers that seem to be for my version of python, when I try things it doesn't recognise keywords and/or parameters.

My lables are 4-bit binary strings .e.g. '0000','0001','0010'........

Can anyone help me please??

Comment: What *is* your version of matplotlib?

Comment: No idea, how would I find out??

Comment: `matplotlib.__version__`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.xticks(x, labels, rotation='vertical')
```

More from similar posting here: [Rotate axis text in python matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998621/rotate-axis-text-in-python-matplotlib/23009503)

And from matplotlib here: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_rotation.html

Comment: I've tried using the rotation parameter but it won't recognise it

Comment: What's your version of matplotlib? I assume python=2.7? Also, what's the error message? Would be good to share your codes here just to be sure.