# Matplotlib - plot problem - Graph configuratuion

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having trouble making my graphic more attractive for a publication, I'm not a programmer, but I found an easy way to make the graphic below. The bars are too thick and I'm not able to put the label on the left side. Also, the legend of the bars are superimposed, could someone help me?

```
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter

df = pd.DataFrame({'country': [40.91, 23.68, 21.53, 55.77, 47.50,
62.59]}) 
df.index = ['Linha de Produção – 1', 'Linha de Produção – 2', 'Linha de Produção – 3', 'Linha de Produção – 4', 'Linha de Produção – 5', 'Linha de Produção – 6'] 
df = df.sort_values(by='country',ascending=False) df["cumpercentage"] = 
df["country"].cumsum()/df["country"].sum()*100

fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
ax.bar(df.index, df["country"], color="C0") 
ax2 = ax.twinx() 
ax2.plot(df.index, df["cumpercentage"], color="C1", marker="D", ms=7) 
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter())

plt.ylabel('NOME DO EIXO Y') 
plt.grid(True)

ax.tick_params(axis="y", colors="C0")    
ax2.tick_params(axis="y", colors="C1")
plt.show()
```

[image: Jupyter plot]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10998621/1216776

Comment: Thanks. Now I have to figure out how to change the Y-axis label..

Comment: ax.set_ylabel('Time')

Answer (score 2):

Use width = 0.1 for bar width:

```
ax.bar(df.index, df["country"], color="C0", width = 0.1)
```