# How do you rotate x axis tick labels in subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, axis-labels, xticks

I am trying to rotate the x axis labels for every subplot. Here is my code:

```
fig.set_figheight(10)
fig.set_figwidth(20)
ax.set_xticklabels(dr_2012['State/UT'], rotation = 90)

ax[0, 0].bar(dr_2012['State/UT'], dr_2012['Primary Total'])
ax[0, 0].set_title('Dropout Ratios 2012-2013 (Primary)')

ax[0, 1].bar(dr_2012['State/UT'], dr_2012['Upper Primary Total'])
ax[0, 1].set_title('Dropout Ratios 2012-2013 (Upper Primary)')

ax[1, 0].bar(dr_2012['State/UT'], dr_2012['Secondary Total'])
ax[1, 0].set_title('Dropout Ratios 2012-2013 (Secondary)')

ax[1, 1].bar(dr_2012['State/UT'], dr_2012['HS Total'])
ax[1, 1].set_title('Dropout Ratios 2012-2013 (HS)')
```

[image: subplot]

None of the usual things seem to work for me. I have tried ax.set_xticklabels and ax.tick_params. I have also tried looping through the ticks using ax.get_xticklabels and even that didn't work. It always gave me this error -

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'set_xticklabels'/'get_xticklabels'/'tick_params'
```

I am at a loss. Why wouldn't it be working?

Comment: what about `fig.xticks(dr_2012['State/UT'], rotation = "vertical")`?

Comment: Hey, in order to get better answers please follow this guide for posting questions on Stack Overflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. 


That being said I think you need to set if for each plot in your subplot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rotate axis text in python matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998621/rotate-axis-text-in-python-matplotlib)

Answer (score 10):

Use `tick_params` on the `AxesSubplot`, but `ax` in your case is an np array of `AxesSubplot` objects.

Fix

```
ax[1][0].tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)
```

Sample usage

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig,ax =  plt.subplots(2,2)
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(1,5)
ax[0][0].plot(x,x*x)
ax[0][0].set_title('square')
ax[0][0].tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)

ax[0][1].plot(x,np.sqrt(x))
ax[0][1].set_title('square root')
ax[0][1].tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)

ax[1][0].plot(x,np.exp(x))
ax[1][0].set_title('exp')
ax[1][0].tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)

ax[1][1].plot(x,np.log10(x))
ax[1][1].set_title('log')
ax[1][1].tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Using tick_params also has the added benefit of getting rid of "UserWarning: set_ticklabels() should only be used with a fixed number of ticks, i.e. after set_ticks() or using a FixedLocator."