# How to wrap the x-axis labels for a box plot visualisation in Python?

Tags: python, word-wrap, axis-labels

I have plotted a box plot with Seaborn. However, the x-axis labels are overlapping. Is there a way to wrap the labels (continue the labels in the next line down) to prevent them from overlapping?

(I would not like to rotate the labels either)

[Screenshot of box plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQDes.png)

```
(sns.boxplot(data=train.select_dtypes(int)))
```

Comment: Wrapping opens another can of worms. Your best bet is rotating them: [Rotate axis text in python matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998621/rotate-axis-text-in-python-matplotlib)

Comment: try plt.xticks(rotation=90)