# Issue with y-ticks alignment in pandas bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, yaxis, grouped-bar-chart

here is the data and code that I'm using to plot the bar chart as shown in the output plot. The issue is with y-ticks, I need to have y-ticks aligned in a vertical manner such that they cover/coincides with all four bars. If we use rot = 'some int value' the ticks rotate, but they do not exactly align vertically covering four bars.

| Polymer | Depth | Residual time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HPAM7030 | 50 | 1159 |
| HPAM7030 | 100 | 1638 |
| HPAM7030 | 200 | 2170 |
| HPAM7030 | 500 | 2718 |
| APAM7525 | 50 | 2040 |
| APAM7525 | 100 | 3101 |
| APAM7525 | 200 | 4176 |
| APAM7525 | 500 | 5270 |

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use(['science', 'notebook', 'grid'])
df.pivot(index = 'Polymer', columns = 'Depth', values = 'Residual time').plot(kind='barh')
plt.title('Residual time of different polymers (2 year simulation)')
plt.ylabel("Type of Polymer")
plt.xlabel("Residual time (Days)")
plt.show()
```

[image: output plot]

Comment: I don't know how you rotate the labels but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998621/rotate-axis-text-in-python-matplotlib) are various versions listed for x-labels.  Those for y-labels are equivalent. You can add the keyword [`va="center"` (options: 'center' | 'top' | 'bottom' | 'baseline')](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/text_props.html)

Comment: the link is useful....if we include plt.yticks(rotation=90, va='center') it works...thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it easier to use the Axes object returned by the pandas plotting method and set the y tick label alignment to `'center'`:

```
ax = df.pivot(index = 'Polymer', columns = 'Depth', values = 'Residual time').plot(kind='barh', rot=90)
ax.set_title('Residual time of different polymers (2 year simulation)')
ax.set(ylabel="Type of Polymer",xlabel="Residual time (Days)")
ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticklabels(), va="center")
```

[image]

Comment: For both types of polymer on the y-axis, I need to have the bars aligned in increasing orders i.e 50, 100, 200 and 500 from the top of the y-axis...just to reverse the order in which they are plotted now...is it possible?

Comment: yes, just sort the columns before plotting: `df.pivot(index = 'Polymer', columns = 'Depth', values = 'Residual time').sort_values(by='Depth', axis=1, ascending=False).plot(kind='barh', rot=90)`

Comment: it works....but the legend of depth also changes and gives value in descending order starting from 500 on top and going down...is it possible to keep the legend as it is now (in the ascending manner like in the figure above)?

Comment: in this case it's easier to plot as usual and then invert the y axis: `ax = df.pivot(index = 'Polymer', columns = 'Depth', values = 'Residual time').plot(kind='barh', rot=90)` followed by `ax.invert_yaxis()`.